# How to see my own actual Oracle SQL statement that is being executed as normal user

Tags: oracle, session, sql-grant

How to see my own actual Oracle SQL statement that is being executed as normal user not DBA?
Which grants are needed? v_$session? ...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle v$ views are named `V_$VIEWNAME` and their synonyms are created as: `V$VIEWNAME`

You need to give the `SELECT` rights on it as follows:

```
SQL> grant select on v_$session to <your_user>;
```

Comment: I get the following error in my session browser: SELECT privilege on either V$SQLTEXT_WITH_NEWLINES or V$SQLTEXT is required

Comment: Try to give rights on `V_$SQLTEXT` before giving grants on `v_$session`

Comment: I am talking about `Grant`

Comment: Can you please show me the statement of grant that you have executed for `v_$session`?

Comment: grant select on V_$SQLTEXT to <your_user>; then grant select on v_$session to <your_user>;

Comment: And what exact error you are facing and in which statement?

Comment: I am using toad as a client and when switching to the session browser to monitor my own SQLs, I get "SELECT privilege on either V$SQLTEXT_WITH_NEWLINES or V$SQLTEXT is require"